# Combine logs from multiple systems into a single user friendly view

Tags: symfony, logging

I have several Symfony projects generating logs. I want to be able to view these logs in a single place. This is my plan…

1. Each system writes logs to separate folder in an AWS s3 bucket
2. A Laravel project will then access these logs probably by pulling
   them down to local store. Using Arcanedev Logviewer I will then view
   the currently available logs.

Has anyone been able to write Symfony logs directly to an AWS s3 bucket (I've only found reference to uploading them using a cron schedule)?

As an aside, has anyone come across a web based log service that allows you to simply view logs in a format as good as Arcanedev Logviewer. We currently use Cloudwatch which is good for what it does and certainly has its place but for me the killer feature of Arcanedev Logviewer is this screen…

[Arcanedev Logviewer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZSSr.png)

Thank you

Gary

Comment: You could have your project access/fetch your remote logs via SFTP or similar and do your stuff. I don't think you can, but I'm unsure if you can set monolog path to an external address..

Comment: You can't use S3, because you can't do incremental writes to an S3 object (they're written atomically, with a single HTTPS PUT). If you're running inside AWS, or have a VPN connection to AWS, you could use EFS. Or you could use any other on-prem remote filesystem. But I recommend looking at [FluentD](https://docs.fluentd.org/) to capture your logs and send them to some aggregation server such as Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks @Bossman, I think you can set Monolog to use an external drive as you can certainly send data to Cloudwatch, Slack or email for example. So (without having done it) I'm sure we can write to an external drive.

Comment: @kdgregory thanks, I will investigate a little first then.